# Where are graphically pleasing examples of Lists

Tags: android, listactivity, listadapter

Anyone know of good code examples of how to make lists look different than your everyday average black list or more graphically pleasing than you usually see in android apps.  I've looked through google code but haven't found too many.  I'm looking for different and eye catching lists.  I hope this question isn't too generic.  Also i'm open to anything, code, examples, blog posts, etc, you name it.  I've really struggled with lists and making them look more snazzy.  I'm talking more the code level not the graphics or icons used.

Comment: It is impossible to answer the question, because we don't know what slim thinks is "more graphically pleasing than you usually see in android apps". That is a subjective measure. slim: you will be better served by coming up with screenshots or something and asking more focused questions (e.g., "how do I get the icon on the left" or "how do I have a black-on-white theme").

Answer (score 0):

These posts can help you to create a custom ListView with any layout you wish

http://www.aeoth.net/blog/2010/03/11/android-dev-custom-listadapter/

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/